# OracleMediaObjects(日本語対応）をwindows10で動作させる方法がありますか？

Tags: windows-10

オラクルメディアオブジェクト（oracl Media objects)のアプリをwindows１０で使用したいが、下記メッセージがでて使用できません。

「このアプリはお使いのpcでは実行できません」

現在のOSは　
エディション  Windows 10 Pro
バージョン   21H1
インストール日 ‎2021/‎07/‎21
OS ビルド  19043.1237
エクスペリエンス    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
です。

下記のOSでは動作可能です。
　エディション Windows 10 Home
バージョン   1709
OS ビルド  1629943

OMOの情報は下記に
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Media_Objects
にあります。

Comment: このソフトを持っていないので、確認できませんが、互換モードで試して見てください。互換モードはexeを右クリック→プロパティ→互換性で設定できます。

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/%E4%BB%A5%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92-windows-10-%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938

Comment: MSのプログラム互換性のトラブルシューテングツールの回答は　「見つかった問題点　　互換性のないプログラム　　解決済み　☑あり」でした。　よくわからないのは　質問にも書いたのですが　別のウィンドウ１０　（Home )では動作します。

Comment: トラブルシューテングではなく、互換モードでこのプログラムを実行するにチェックを入れ、windows7等そのプラグラムが想定しているOSに設定してみてください。homeのPCとproのPCのハードウェアの違いもあるかもしれませんので、そのあたりもチェックしてみてください。

Comment: 両Windowsは共に64bitでしょうか？ 質問文に追記願います。

Comment: Windows　Homeの方は　32-bit operating system x64 based processerです。互換モードでこのプログラムを実行するにチェック入れたが駄目でした。